# JavaScript Coding Challenge help - Quiz Question Do While Loop

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a coding challenge that requests we ask just one multiple choice question - if the answer is correct, it prints a congrats and exits the program. if wrong, it offers the user the chance to try again or exit the program. I've only been coding for a few weeks and it still simpler for me to use if/else if for this - but we need to use a Do While loop. Below is what i have so far and any advice would be appreciated:

```
let answer = [""]
do {
    prompt("What shape is the Earth? \nA: Square\nB: Triangle\nC: Round\nD: Flat");
} while (answer != C);
    console.log("I'm sorry you're an idiot.")
    let retry = alert("Try again? Y/N")

if (retry == Y) {
    //how to reset loop from here?
}
else if (retry == N) {
    //how to exit program? 
}
if(answer === C) {
    console.log("Congratulations! You're not an idiot :)")
}
```

Comment: Well firstly, I personally would not do it in a prompt loop, Chrome (and most other browsers) will usually prompt the user to block popups if they appear too frequently. Which will break your code. Additionally, you never assign a value to `answer`, you need something like `answer = prompt('what is 1+1');`

Comment: Here's the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/76sem12n/ (the key is to move the logic that checks the user's input *inside* the loop, so you can exit or not based on the user input)

Comment: Here is my suggestion, move the handling of the answer into its own JS function. i.e `function checkAnswer(){doStuff}` then move your question into its own function `function question(s){doStuff}`. If the user gets the answer wrong, then you can call `question()` from the `answer()` function

Comment: @ChrisG would it not be better to explain to him what he was doing wrong, instead of just fixing the code? #JustAsking

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer That is precisely the wrong approach, you do not keep calling the next function from within a function. It'll literally create a stack overflow error :)

Comment: @ChrisG i was thinking something along this line https://jsfiddle.net/x0ubo9hz/ that doesnt overflow, or go into an infinite loop, but i understand what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys - I do prefer working out the solution but thanks  to both of you. (Also, im a she/her lol)

Comment: The best way to figure this out is to create a flow diagram first, using good old pen and paper. This will show that all decisions need to happen inside the loop, basically.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer It absolutely will overflow if you keep answering wrong, then retry, because that code never leaves the call stack, it keeps putting a new function call on top. Just because that won't happen quick on a modern machine doesn't mean it isn't extremely bad practice and you should unlearn this immediately, let alone teach it to others.

Comment: @ChrisG fair point, i actually didnt think of that thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put your code in a snippet:

```js
let answer = [""]
do {
    prompt("What shape is the Earth? \nA: Square\nB: Triangle\nC: Round\nD: Flat");
} while (answer != C);
    console.log("I'm sorry you're an idiot.")
    let retry = alert("Try again? Y/N")

if (retry == Y) {
    //how to reset loop from here?
}
else if (retry == N) {
    //how to exit program? 
}
if(answer === C) {
    console.log("Congratulations! You're not an idiot :)")
}
```

Now click the **Run code snippet** button above and watch what happens.

Do you see the error message? That is the first thing to fix, and this is your first step in learning how to *debug your code*.

Debugging is one of the most valuable skills you will need in programming. For JavaScript in a browser, you will want to get familiar with the *Developer Tools* that are built into every browser. If you use Chrome or the new Edge browser, here is a [guide to the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).

The DevTools include an interactive Console where you can see error messages and type in expressions to see what they do. They also include a Source view where you can set breakpoints in your source code and look at your variables, and many other debugging features.

A Stack Overflow snippet like the one above has a built-in Console so you can see the error message right here in the page. For code you're running in your own web page, use the browser's developer tools to see errors, test expressions, set breakpoints, and view your variables.

Comment: The answer is that OP needs to learn how to debug JavaScript code. If they don't learn this, they will forever be asking Stack Overflow questions about "why doesn't my code work?" I have provided tools and recommendations on how to learn this skill. Is this not an answer? "Answering" the question by providing correct working code is the worst thing we could do here!

Comment: Your answer is helpful advice obviously, and it's basically the exact thing I'd post. If this were any other website.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, I appreciate the advice and will be looking through it. The class i am on at the moment doesn't seem to give us any actual teaching - more just a couple pages on what each function is and then gives us tasks at the end to submit - so this kind of advice is also really helpful.

Comment: @Nyxerian I am glad it is helpful. Trust me, when you learn the art of debugging, you will feel like you have gained a superpower! :-)

Comment: @ChrisG your approach is also helpful - I have been using Miro.com for my flow charts and working out my processes. I am also reading Eloquent JavaScript to get more info. Thank you for your help as well.